# Analysing functions

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $f(x)$ be a twice differentiable function on $[1,3]$ and $f(1) = f(3)$.
$|f''(x)|<2$, for all $x$ in $[1,3]$.

Then in $[1,3]$, what is the range of $|f'(x)|$?

The first approach to this problem was applying Rolle's theorem, but the only information it provides is that there exists a $c$ in $[1,3]$ where $f'(x)$ is zero. The second approach, although a bad one, was assuming $f(x)$ to be a quadratic function with leading coefficient less than 2. But since the leading coefficient can vary, it did not provide a definite set of values for $|f'(x)|$. Which other approach can I use here?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  Your idea of Rolle's theorem is a good one.  Now use the facts that $f'(x)=\int_c^xf''(t)dt$ and $\int_1^3 f'(t)dt=0$  You should be able to find a $c$ that lets $|f'(x)|$ get as large as possible.

Comment: Can you please explain further?